# dask dataframe from python list of tuples

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I am really new to dask. I want to create a dask dataframe from a python list of tuples. In pandas, you can use `DataFrame.from_records` to convert  a list of tuples to a dataframe. What function can give me same functionality in dask.
My data looks a bit like this

> [(21262, 'booking', 'NULL'), (21262, 'booking', 'NULL'), (21262, 'booking', 'NULL'), (21262, 'booking', ''), (21262, 'booking', 'NULL')]

I am using this code to perform the task right now. Is this correct way of doing this.

```
import pandas as pd
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd

names = ['id', 'status', 'reg_entry']
dfs = dask.delayed(pd.DataFrame.from_records)(cursor.fetchall(), columns=names)

df = dd.from_delayed(dfs)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Can you provide code samples what you did already?

Comment: @Florian sorry for not being clearer the first time. I am new to this forum and in learning phase. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try creating a dask dataframe from an existing pandas dataframe (to be able to use all pandas constructors):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(21262, 'booking', 'NULL'), (21262, 'booking', 'NULL'), (21262, 'booking', 'NULL'), (21262, 'booking', ''), (21262, 'booking', 'NULL')])
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)
```

Comment: Thank you @Tina . So there is no direct function available in dask to ingest such data and one has to pass through the pandas?

Comment: apparently, yes.